# Content Replacement

Tags: powershell, content-deployment

I have a problem with content deployment that I need to fix using a script to replace content throughout the site.  SharePoint handles relative urls already but editors have to use an internal url which then needs to be replaced with an external url when deployed.

Does anyone have/know of a script that will fix the content without messing up the publishing states?

I'm starting my own script to do this but if theres already one out there I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Are the internal and external URLs different?  Do they have the same path?  Or, is it just their domains that are different.

Comment: its just the domains that need to be replaced for associated sites... I've written a script to do it and need to add it to this as an answer.